# Apply something to certain value of a hash, return the whole hash

Tags: ruby, functional-programming, method-chaining

What is the proper way of doing so in Ruby in a functional and immutable way:

```
a = { price: 100, foo: :bar, bar: :baz }

def reduced_price(row)
  row.merge(price: row[:price] / 2)
end

reduced_price(a) # => { price: 50, foo: :bar, bar: :baz }
```

I don't want to mutate anything and I don't like the consctruction `row.merge(key: row[:key])` because it repeats the `:key` and refers to `row` twice. If there would be something like:

```
{a: 1, b: 2}.apply_to_key(:a) { |x| x * 10 } # => {a: 10, b: 2}
```

it would be great.

To sum up, I want a method that, when given a key, updates a single value of a hash by that key using the previous value, and then returns the whole hash.

Answer (score 1):

And while I was writing the question, I have found the answer. Since SO suggests sharing my knowledge Q&A-style, here it is:

```
{a: 1, b: 2}.merge(a: nil) { |_, v| v * 10 } # => {a: 10, b: 2}
```

When you pass a block to `hash.merge(other_hash)`, it will be executed for each pair of `other_hash` with parameters `key, oldval, newval` and should return resulting value. In a case above, my `other_hash` contains only one key I wanted to alter, and from the three params I care only for the second, `old_val`, to use it in my block.

It's perfectly chainable and doesn't mutate a thing. It has a bit of redundancy (having to pass `nil` or any other value to `other_hash`, having to ignore first parameter of the block), but I guess it's the closest I could get.

If you can suggest better answer, I will consider accepting it.